# Spring-Cloud-AWS maxNumberOfMessages per queue

Tags: amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

The SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory in spring-cloud-aws provides a way to configure the MaxNumberOfMessages to pull from an SQS queue.  See [spring cloud docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/1.2.3.RELEASE/multi/multi__messaging.html#_the_simplemessagelistenercontainerfactory)

If an application is listening to more than one queue.  How can the MaxNumberOfMessages be set differently for each queue?